# How can I vectorize the following piece of code in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

y is 5000 x 1 vector containing numbers 1 to 10. I can convert y to Y (5000 x 10 matrix) such that

```
Y = zeros(5000,10);
for i = 1:5000
    Y(i,y(i))=1;
end
```

Can I achieve the same result without using for loop?

Comment: When you want to assign `1` to the whole matrix, why don't you use `Y = ones(5000, 10)` in the first place?

Comment: How do you use `Y` later? If you use it in Matrix products, like `Y*A`, you can instead write `A(y,:)`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sparse`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) for that:

```
y = [8 5 7 4 2 6 4]; % example y. Arbitrary size
M = 10; % maximum possible value in y
Y = full(sparse(1:numel(y), y, 1, numel(y), M));
```

Equivalently, it can be done with [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
Y = accumarray([(1:numel(y)).' y(:)], 1, [numel(y) M]);
```

Answer (score 5):

A solution using [`implicit expansion`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
Y = y == 1:10;
```

It creates a logical matrix. If you need a double matrix you can write:

```
Y = double(y == 1:10);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @LuisMendo answer, you can also use [`sub2ind`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html):

```
Y = zeros(5,10);                      % Y preallocation, zeros(numel(y),max_column)
y = [8 5 7 4 2];                      % Example y
Y(sub2ind(size(Y),1:numel(y),y)) = 1  % Linear indexation
```

---

Noticed that this method is slightly different than `accumarray` and `sparse` if there are duplicate pairs of `[row,column]` index:

```
% The linear index assigns the last value:
Y = zeros(2,2);
Y(sub2ind(size(Y),[1 1],[1,1])) = [3,4] % 4 overwrite 3
```

Result:

```
Y =

   4   0
   0   0
```

VS

```
% Sparse sum the values:
Y = full(sparse([1 1],[1,1], [3,4], 2, 2)) % 3+4
```

Result:

```
Y =

   7   0
   0   0
```

Comment: In the question there cannot be duplicate pairs, as each value goes to a different row

Comment: It was just a warning to indicate that both method have different behaviour even if it was not directly related to the question. But thanks :)